# "not a valid month" while inserting timestamp into table

Tags: sql, oracle

Error while trying to insert a query which transforms multiple merged date(eg.20230208065521019355) into proper timestamp format to a new column.

```
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE2(RC_DATETIME)
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(RC_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:FF'),  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF')
FROM NEWTABLE;
```

Upon just executing the SELECT statement I get the query but while including the INSERT I get the error of 'not valid month'.

Data within the RC_TIMESTAMP(VARCHAR) are the merged data which are as follows:
20230208065521019355, 20230208065523019356, 20230208065532019357, etc.

RC_DATETIME has VARCHAR(35) datatype.

I have tried reordering the format of TO_CHAR, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF' to 'Mon-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF' to name a few.

Comment: Please use only the tag for the DBMS you are using

Comment: You say that `RC_TIMESTAMP` is a string that look like this: `'20230208065521019355'`. Why then are you trying to convert this string into a timestamp with a format `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:FF'`? Why do you suddenly expect dashes and colons in the string?

Comment: On a side note: It's always a bad idea not to use the appropriate data type. If you want to store a timestamp, store it as a timestamp. It was a bad idea to store it as a string containing a long number. It is just as bad an idea to store it in a string containing the formatted timsetamp. (I admit, it's more readable than the mere number, but why make this a string at all?)

Comment: Thorsten Kettner, it is one of the tasks I have been given as an intern, RC_TIMESTAMP is actually a substr of merged data. So at first, I extracted the date, inserted it into a new column and now I'm trying to convert the whole column into an actual timestamp format. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Okay. It is a good idea to get cleaner data. '2023-02-08 06:55:21.019355' is more readable than '20230208065521019355'. But it still allows for invalid timestamps, such as  '2023-02-33 00:00:00.000000' or even 'this is not a timestamp'. It is a mistake to make `RC_DATETIME` a string. It must be a timestamp in order to prevent invalid dates.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? TO_CHAR and TO_TIMSTAMP are product specific functions.

Comment: @jarlh I am using Oracle.

Comment: Oracle users tend to use VARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR. (I don't know why.)

Comment: @jarlh  (Me neither.) I'm a beginner here, but from what i have noticed is that even if i deliberately specify a datatype to be VARCHAR , it auto-changes itself to VARCHAR2.

Comment: @jarlh simply because of [VARCHAR Data Type](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#sthref74): "*Do not use the `VARCHAR` data type. Use the `VARCHAR2` data type instead. Although the `VARCHAR` data type is currently synonymous with `VARCHAR2`, the `VARCHAR` data type is scheduled to be redefined as a separate data type used for variable-length character strings compared with different comparison semantics.*"

Answer (score 1):

From what you posted:

Source table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE newtable (rc_timestamp)
  2  AS (SELECT '20230208065521019355' FROM DUAL);

Table created.
```

Target table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE newtable2
  2  (rc_datetime   VARCHAR2 (35));

Table created.
```

Insert:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO newtable2 (rc_datetime)
  2     SELECT TO_CHAR (TO_TIMESTAMP (rc_timestamp, 'yyyymmddhh24missff6'),
  3                     'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss:ff')
  4       FROM newtable;

1 row created.
```

---

However, you'd rather store timestamps into a timestamp column, **not** as a string. What benefit do you expect? It causes problems in later data processing.

```
SQL> DROP TABLE newtable2;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE newtable2
  2  (rc_datetime   TIMESTAMP);

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO newtable2
  2     SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (rc_timestamp, 'yyyymmddhh24missff6') FROM newtable;

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

You commented that you still have the "not a valid month" error.

It means that data - at position where `TO_TIMESTAMP` expects a valid month value (01, 02, ..., 12) - contains something else. What? No idea, you have all the data. Try to find it by selecting a substring (month starts at position 5 and takes 2 places):

```
SQL> SELECT rc_timestamp, SUBSTR (rc_timestamp, 5, 2) month FROM newtable;

RC_TIMESTAMP         MO
-------------------- --
20230208065521019355 02

SQL>
```

Invalid data is most probably here:

```
SELECT rc_timestamp
  FROM newtable
 WHERE SUBSTR (rc_timestamp, 5, 2) NOT BETWEEN '01' AND '12';
```

Once you find invalid values, you'll decide what to do with it. Maybe you'll ignore those values (so you'd include appropriate `where` clause into the `insert` statement), or fix it (somehow; can't tell *how* as it depends on what you'll find), or ...

---

If you want to identify invalid values during insert, a simple option is a loop with an inner `begin-exception-end` block which lets you capture those values and still proceed with other row(s). Something like this:

```
create table invalid_values as
  select id, value from source_table where 1 = 2;

begin
  for cur_r in (select * from source_table) loop
    begin
      insert into newtable2 ...

    exception
      when others then 
        insert into invalid_values (id, value) values (cur_r.id, cur_r.value);
    end;
  end loop;
end;
```

Once you're done, `select * from invalid_value` so that you could deal with what's left.

That *should* be OK as you have 10.000 rows so loop won't take *infinite* time to complete. True, it will be slower than set-oriented operation, but ... you have to fetch invalid rows, somehow.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, but the issue still persist even though i have changed the datatype to TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Indeed, one of the row had jumbled data(615700001000000379). Im working on deleting that row and will get back. Also, there are like 10k + rows so is there any easy way to identify the false data down the road?

Comment: I added some more info into the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you are saying. Source table.column is NEWTABLE.RC_TIMESTAMP. Target table.column is NEWTABLE2.RC_DATETIME. Why / where would you "include RC_DATETIME"? What does it mean that "RC_TIMESTAMP hadn't been created"? It is the *source*, it already exists, doesn't it? Could you edit the original question and post sample data as well as desired result, explaining what's going on and what exactly doesn't work?